# Python script not executing on reboot (Raspberry Pi 400)

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I really hope someone could help me.

The main objective of my script is controlling volume levels in my rasp with 2 GPIO buttons.
In order to get that i am currently using this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from subprocess import call, run
import time
import os

up = 11
down = 13

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(up,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(down,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)



def buttonStateChanged(pin):
    mute = False
    while True:
        if not GPIO.input(up) | GPIO.input(down):
            if mute == False:
                call(["xdotool", "key", "XF86AudioMute"], shell=False)
                time.sleep(0.2)
                mute = True
                
            if mute == True:
                call(["xdotool", "key", "XF86AudioMute"], shell=False)
                time.sleep(0.2)
                mute = True
                
        if not GPIO.input(up):
            call(["xdotool", "key", "XF86AudioRaiseVolume"], shell=False)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        if not GPIO.input(down):
            call(["xdotool", "key", "XF86AudioLowerVolume"], shell=False)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        
GPIO.add_event_detect(11, GPIO.BOTH, callback=buttonStateChanged)
GPIO.add_event_detect(13, GPIO.BOTH, callback=buttonStateChanged)

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

When I try this out in my terminal by using
`python volume.py`
i work flawless.

As i want to have it always running I want to run the programm as soon as my rasp turns on, here is where problems begin.
I have added it to crontab as a running script together with another script that turns off and reboot my rasp:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from subprocess import call, run
from datetime import datetime
import time


# pushbutton connected to this GPIO pin, using pin 5 also has the benefit of
# waking / powering up Raspberry Pi when button is pressed

# if button pressed for at least this long then shut down. if less then reboot.
shutdownMinSeconds = 3

# button debounce time in seconds
debounceSeconds = 0.01


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

buttonPressedTime = None


def buttonStateChanged(pin):
    global buttonPressedTime

    if not (GPIO.input(pin)):
        # button is down
        if buttonPressedTime is None:
            buttonPressedTime = datetime.now()
    else:
        # button is up
        if buttonPressedTime is not None:
            elapsed = (datetime.now() - buttonPressedTime).total_seconds()
            buttonPressedTime = None
            if elapsed >= shutdownMinSeconds:
                # button pressed for more than specified time, shutdown
                call(['shutdown', '-h', 'now'], shell=False)
            elif elapsed >= debounceSeconds:
                # button pressed for a shorter time, reboot
#                 run('vcgencmd display_power 0 2', shell = True)
#                 time.sleep(1)
#                 run('vcgencmd display_power 1 2', shell = True)
                call(['shutdown', '-r', 'now'], shell=False)
                
GPIO.add_event_detect(5, GPIO.BOTH, callback=buttonStateChanged)

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

The thing here is that this code DOES work when I set it on crontab

`@reboot python /Desktop/reboot.py`

I have also added it to /etc/rc.local creating a script that does the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo python /Desktop/volume.py &
sudo python /Desktop/hold.py &
```

Having a result of being able to turn off and reboot but not being able to turn volume up/down

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me to figure out what am I doing wrong and help me find a possible solution, thanks everyone

Comment: try adding python exact path, it should be `/bin/python` but check typing `which python` on your terminal

Comment: I did this sudo /usr/bin/python /Desktop/volume.py and reboot.py and worked, but when I put that in the .sh it is just reboot that works and volume still does nothing.

Comment: Check if cron is enabled `systemctl status cron.service`

Comment: Let me show you what i get after doing that 
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-02-21 18:49:51 CET; 12min ago
   Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 403 (cron)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 769ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
├─403 /usr/sbin/cron -f
├─544 sudo /usr/bin/python /home/alex/Desktop/volume.py
├─545 sudo /usr/bin/python /home/alex/Desktop/hold.py
├─561 /usr/bin/python /home/alex/Desktop/volume.py
└─562 /usr/bin/python /home/alex/Desktop/hold.py

Comment: @Colevakun - please don't add output to the comments, edit your question and add it there. It's unreadable in the comments ...

Comment: It looks odd that you do exactly the same thing if `mute` is True and if it's False! Why do you even bother testing?